# Get multiple element in join on sql request into collection

Tags: magento2, collection, magento-2.1.3

I have a table "test_brand" and a table "test_vehicles". In "test_vehicles" I put a parameter which is "brand_id". Now I want to get in my template a collection with all brand and for each brand all their vehicles.

I found no tutorials about this on the net so I tried myself but I can't found the solution, can you help me please ?

I have the model for brand and vehicles. So I made for each a simple Collection like :

```
<?php
namespace Test\Vehicles\Model\ResourceModel\Brand;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection {

  protected $_idFieldName = \Test\Vehicles\Model\Brand::BRAND_ID;

  /**
  * Define resource model
  *
  * @return void
  */
  protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Test\Vehicles\Model\Brand', 'Test\Vehicles\Model\ResourceModel\Brand');
  }

  public function getBrandShowcase($brand, $vehicle) {
    $this->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->join(
      array('vehicle' => $this->_vehicle->getResource()->getMainTable()),
      'main_table.'.$this->_brand->getIdFieldName().' = vehicle.brand_id',
      array('vehicle_name' => 'name')
    );
    return $this;
  }

}
```

And in my block I call the function but I get an error :

> Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Test\Vehicles\Model\Brand) with the
>   same ID "1" already exists.

Here is my model :

```
<?php
namespace Test\Vehicles\Model;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Brand extends AbstractModel {
  const BRAND_ID = 'entity_id'; // We define the id fieldname

  /**
  * Prefix of model events names
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $_eventPrefix = 'test'; // parent value is 'core_abstract'

  /**
  * Name of the event object
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $_eventObject = 'brand'; // parent value is 'object'

  /**
  * Name of object id field
  *
  * @var string
  */
  protected $_idFieldName = self::BRAND_ID; // parent value is 'id'

  /**
  * Initialize resource model
  *
  * @return void
  */
  protected function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Test\Vehicles\Model\ResourceModel\Brand');
  }
}
```

And there is the ressource model :

```
<?php
namespace Test\Vehicles\Model\ResourceModel;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Brand extends AbstractDb {

  /**
  * Initialize resource model
  *
  * @return void
  */
  protected function _construct() {
    // Table Name and Primary Key column
    $this->_init('test_brand', 'entity_id');
  }
}
```

I thinked about a solution and maybe I need to use the collection of vehicle to get all vehicles about a brand_id but I don't know how to build it. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Maybe I've found a solution... I'm working in

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In my Brand model I put a function to get the Collection of Vehicles and in my template in my foreach when I get my Brand object I call this method.